# React Native import package only on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to import a package only on Android here is the package anyone has any idea if this is possible?

```
import {ProcessingManager} from 'react-native-video-processing';
```

Comment: Yes, you can branch your codes into different OS, try to add this line in `App.android.js` (or similar JS OS-specific files).

Comment: That doesn't really help the entire file is a component which is load into my main stack, I tried to rename it to .android but it still loads the files which in turn loads that import package which crashes my app

Answer (score 6):

### You have two way for this:

#### First way:

You can separate platform code by creating two different files `your_file_name.android.js` and `your_file_name.ios.js`.

For example, you have to have this files in your directory

```
BigButton.ios.js
BigButton.android.js
```

You can then require the component as follows:

```
import BigButton from './BigButton'
```

reference: [react netive](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions)

#### Second way:

I am not sure for this way

```
var ProcessingManager;

if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
    ProcessingManager = require('react-native-video-processing');
}
```

Comment: If you use the second you might face issues where platform specific functions are no longer available, use the first way

Answer (score 0):

This Works:

var DocPicker = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? require('react-native-file-picker') : require('react-native-document-picker');

Comment: Where will you define this in a functional component?
Inside functional component or outside of it ?