# How to get React Native to require/import function from package only on Android OS

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, react-native-maps

#### How can I import a function only for a specific platform?

When using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps) I want to import PROVIDER_GOOGLE from react-native-maps only for Android app users, so that I don't overuse the Google Service API (and take advantage of Apple Map's lack of metering). e.g. I only want PROVIDER_GOOGLE imported if the app is running on Android.

```
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
```

#### What does React-Native Documentation suggest?

React native [platform-specific-code](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code) documentation suggests ways of importing components, but doesn't show a pattern to require `PROVIDER_GOOGLE` from react-native-maps. I want react-native-maps itself to be imported for both OS's.

```
const Component = Platform.select({
  ios: () => require('ComponentIOS'),
  android: () => require('ComponentAndroid')
})();

<Component />
```

The other pattern suggested is to have an OS specific file e.g.

```
MyMap.ios.js
MyMap.android.js
```

So I can then require the component as follows:

```
import MyMap from './MyMap';
```

This way I could only have the `PROVIDER_GOOGLE` import in the `MyMap.android.js` flavor.

While this solution works, I'm having to copy/paste literally every thing else, which seems quite inefficient, so was looking for a better method to require the function itself only for a specific platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Let the function exist then require the package and get the function

```
let functionNeeded; if (true) { functionNeeded = require( package ).functionNeeded; }
```

This may be obvious to seasoned users of "require", but wasn't to me based on the [RN documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code) or even similar questions and answers SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287977/can-you-conditionally-import-files-in-react-native) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638475/react-native-import-package-only-on-android). The best solution I found is to use require to extract the package, then you can get the function specifically.

The most efficient solution I found was in an [expo forum post](https://forums.expo.dev/t/platform-specific-imports/24430/3). Reproducing the pattern applied to this problem here:

```
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";

let PROVIDER_GOOGLE;
if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE = require('react-native-maps').PROVIDER_GOOGLE;
}
```